# Hide a div that is part of all pages on one specific page

Tags: theme-development, css, html, child-theme

How can I hide a div (which contains an image) for a specific WordPress page?

I believe my page id is 46:

[image]

Here is the div I am trying to change:

```
<div id="static-footer-image" style="position:absolute; bottom: -15px; z-index: 501;">
    <img src="images/background-bottom.png"/>
</div>
```

And the associated CSS code in my main CSS file:

```
#static-footer-image body.page-id-46 { 
     display: none; 
}
```

It is still showing. What do I do to fix this?

Comment: Your CSS rule is backwards, `body` is not a child of `#static-footer-image`, it should be `body.page-id-46 #static-footer-image`

Comment: thanks, but it is still showing.

Comment: are you sure about the page id? inspect the body tag on rendered html code for that page and confirm please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess from the URL structure, your `%postname%` permalink structure is active. So, a bit of internal CSS can help alternatively, and the syntax is `in_page('page_slug')`:

```
<?php // Do action only on specific page in WP ?>
<?php if( in_page('resourses') ) { ?>
<style>
  #static-footer-image{
      display: none;
  }
</style>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: this is adding unnecesary load to the server, I would go for M-R's answer

Comment: I do agree. Sure, he's right.

Answer (score 11):

Use following CSS

```
body.page-id-46 #static-footer-image { 
     display: none; 
}
```

and make sure "page-id-46" class is applied to body tag and Clear the cache. May be try on another browser or a incognito window.

Answer (score 2):

If that's the page ID, the selector should be

```
body#page-id-46 #static-footer-image
```

not

```
body.page-id-46 #static-footer-image
```

Comment: nope, WP renders `<body class="page page-id-28 page-template ...">` for me, so that's a class

Answer (score 1):

You may have a `display` in CSS so you may try:

```
body.page-id-46 #static-footer-image { 
     display: none !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
body .page-id-46 #static-footer-image { 
     display: none; 
}
```

not this:

```
body.page-id-46 #static-footer-image { 
     display: none; 
}
```

After body give a space and type `.page-id-46 #static-footer-image{display: none;}`
Once again check whether it's a class or id.
in my case, it's an id, here is my code for your reference:

```
body #post-448 .entry-meta-bar
{
    display:none;
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

How would the code look if you wanted to exclude a widget?

The CSS:

```
body.page-id-60748,
.widget_its-single-post { 
     display: none !important; 
}
```

Comment: This is confusing because it looks as though you're asking another question but you appear to be answering a question.

Comment: Mine was more widget orientated then div, I got it working anyway, thanks!